# How to align the text next to the image without it going in a new column right under the image

Tags: html, css

My goal is to align the text next to the image! I've tried applying the **vertical-align:top;** and it quite worked but after you add a little bit more text some of it stays at the top next to the image and the rest falls down right UNDER the image. I've tried using bunch of div's but neither that helped.

Here's the image of my page:

[image]

HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
h1, h5 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pre-header {
    text-align: center;
}

#header-content1-1 {
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Find out who was Avicii!">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>David</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="pre-header">
        <h1 id="header-content1">Avicii - Tim Bergling</h1>
        <h5 id="header-content1-1">Swedish DJ, remixer, record producer, musician, and songwriter</h5>
    </div>
    </header>
<main>
    <hr>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BX2PS5b.jpeg" alt="Image of Avicii">
    <span> this is the textdot oixjf iodfjdoi ndsjfnsjdkf ndsjknf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj sdnfkj nsdjkf nsdjkf ndskjfn kjdsnf jksdnfjk nsdkjf ndsjkfn dskjfn kjsdnf kjdsnfkj dsnfkj ndsjkfn dsjkf ndsjkfn dkjsfn kjdsnf jkdsnf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj dsnkjfn dsjkfndskjfndsjknfjkdsfnjkds nf kjsdnfkjdsnfk</span>
</main>

<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one remaining place where I'd recommend using float.

```css
body {
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
h1, h5 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pre-header {
    text-align: center;
}

#header-content1-1 {
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

img.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Find out who was Avicii!">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>David</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="pre-header">
        <h1 id="header-content1">Avicii - Tim Bergling</h1>
        <h5 id="header-content1-1">Swedish DJ, remixer, record producer, musician, and songwriter</h5>
    </div>
    </header>
<main>
    <hr>
    <img class="float-left" src="https://i.imgur.com/BX2PS5b.jpeg" alt="Image of Avicii">
    <span> this is the textdot oixjf iodfjdoi ndsjfnsjdkf ndsjknf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj sdnfkj nsdjkf nsdjkf ndskjfn kjdsnf jksdnfjk nsdkjf ndsjkfn dskjfn kjsdnf kjdsnfkj dsnfkj ndsjkfn dsjkf ndsjkfn dkjsfn kjdsnf jkdsnf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj dsnkjfn dsjkfndskjfndsjknfjkdsfnjkds nf kjsdnfkjdsnfk</span>
</main>

<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .pre-header{
      text-align: center;
    }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center
      }
      img {
        max-width: 100%
      }
      .image {
        flex-basis: 40%
      }
      .text {
        top: 0;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 1%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>David</title>
    <title>The title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pre-header">
      <h1 id="header-content1">Avicii - Tim Bergling</h1>
      <h5 id="header-content1-1">Swedish DJ, remixer, record producer, musician, and songwriter</h5>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="avicii.jpg" alt="Image of Avicii">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <span> this is the textdot oixjf iodfjdoi ndsjfnsjdkf ndsjknf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj sdnfkj nsdjkf nsdjkf ndskjfn kjdsnf jksdnfjk nsdkjf ndsjkfn dskjfn kjsdnf kjdsnfkj dsnfkj ndsjkfn dsjkf ndsjkfn dkjsfn kjdsnf jkdsnf kjdsnf kjdsnfkj dsnkjfn dsjkfndskjfndsjknfjkdsfnjkds nf kjsdnfkjdsnfk</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Learn More Here: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image.html